# As for UK Standard Visitor Visa application, does it matter my job title?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am planning to visit to the UK as a visiting researcher or a standard visitor as an academic. I got approved by my employer for my research in the UK and I got an invitation from a UK institute, which makes everything looks ready.

But my job title at the current workplace is not a researcher but a manager, which means I am not working as an academic although I have not few academic achievements.

There are two options. First go safe; apply for the visa after my job title has been changed to a researcher. At the beginning of next year, I will be transferred to the affiliated research institute of my company and work there as a researcher before leaving for the research. Second take risk; apply as who I am with good explanation of why I have been invited to an institute in the UK.

What will be your advice?

Answer (score 1):

I'd wait.

Though I wouldn't place the worry about job titles as much of a factor in choosing to do this.

You haven't started your new job yet. 99% chance you will start it as planned, you'll get along with your colleagues just fine and all will be as expected.

But with starting a new job there's always the 1% chance something might be off. I'd hold off on making any big and unnecessary decisions until this stress is out of the way.

I suspect that the UK authorities might also see things somewhat in this way; you're applying for a visa for a overseas transfer despite not even working for the company yet?

This may even be part of why they're putting you with the local affiliate first, they can help and make things go smoother with a transfer than with a direct hire from overseas.